# '老了以后再去考虑吧' this sentence has apectual or modal 了?

Tags: grammar

I'm a student of Chinese. I know the differences about modal and aspectual 了，but this sentence, 老了以后再去考虑吧 confuses me. I think is not modal, because modal should be at the end of the sentence, but a the same time 老 is not a verb, so I can't understand if it is aspectual or modal?

Comment: The 在 should be written as 再

Answer (score 4):

老 can be a verb for "to age/ to get old"

了 in 老了 is an aspect marker that indicates the verb/ action is completed, therefore , 老了 means "aged/ gotten old "

> [老了以后]再去考虑吧] --> [after you've gotten old], then think about it

Examples of 老 as a verb:

- 我老了 = I am getting old
- 看似老了幾年 = seem like aged a few years

*Note: 了 only indicate completion of a verb, it doesn't indicate tense.*